# Preventing duplicate element access when reading an XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I got an XML that I'm trying to parse using LINQ to XML and convert it to an anonymous list of objects. To do so, I come up with the following code snippet:

```
var res = doc
            .Root
            .Elements("Record")
            .Elements("Term")
            .Select(term => new
            {
                LanguageCode = term.Attribute("languageCode").Value,
                ConceptNumber = Convert.ToInt32(term.Attribute("conceptNumber").Value),
                IsHidden = Convert.ToBoolean(term.Attribute("hidden").Value),
                Label = term.Value,

                InputDate = DateTime.Parse(term.Parent.Element("InputDate").Value),
                LastUpdate = DateTime.Parse(term.Parent.Element("LastUpdated").Value)
            }).ToList();
```

Please pay attention to the InputDate & LastUpdate section. As you see, I've to access the **parent node** (say, term.Parent) so that I can access those 2 elements and this looks messy to me. Is there any way to declare term.Parent once and using it over and over again to extract those properties?

Here's an excerpt of the XML I'm trying to read:

```
<Record>
  <Term  languageCode="Prs" conceptNumber="10" hidden="False">Whatever</Term>
  <Status>Approved</Status>
  <Frequency>0</Frequency>
  <InputDate>12/30/1899</InputDate>
  <LastUpdate>10/25/2009</LastUpdate>
</Record>
```

Thank you

Comment: As I see its your first question here. Please, mark the correct answer or reply for current answers if something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976%28VS.90%29.aspx). It creates a new variable inside query and allows to use it multiply times.

In your case it would be

```
var res = (from term in doc.Root.Elements("Record").Elements("Term")
           let parent = term.Parent
           select new
           {
               LanguageCode = term.Attribute("languageCode").Value,
               ConceptNumber = Convert.ToInt32(term.Attribute("conceptNumber").Value),
               IsHidden = Convert.ToBoolean(term.Attribute("hidden").Value),
               Label = term.Value,
               InputDate = parent.Element("InputDate").Value,
               LastUpdate = parent.Element("LastUpdated").Value
           }).ToList();
```

Note that its a code on a pure LINQ syntax that allow you to express ideas much clearer than using extension methods like in your question.

Comment: Well, I actually would like to use the LINQ methods. Does the following answer correspond to the expression you've already provided?

Comment: @Simon Max, I gave you an answer using pure LINQ. This code uses extension methods (Select, SelectMany, Where, etc) under the hood, as BrokenGlass said. I don't see any reason to use this methods direct instead of LINQ syntax (which allow to express your idea clear). "... the following answer..." - what answer? Another one by BrokenGlass?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce an anonymous class in a projection (This is similar to what `let` does under the hood) and then use `SelectMany()` to flatten using the extra properties:

```
var results = doc.Elements("Record")
                 .Select( x => new 
                  {
                    Terms = x.Elements("Term"),
                    InputDate = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("InputDate").Value),
                    LastUpdate = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("LastUpdate").Value)
                  }) 
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Terms, (record,term) => new
                 {
                    LanguageCode = term.Attribute("languageCode").Value,
                    ..
                    InputDate = record.InputDate,
                    LastUpdate = record.LastUpdate
                 });
```